# Wordpress pagination not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I'm building a wordpress theme from scratch and I want to display the pagination on the blog pag but it is not working.

here is my index.php

```
<?php get_header();?>

<div class="container-fluid" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="row" style="display: flex; background-color: #F5F5F5;">
        <div class="page-content col-md-9">
            <div style="padding:0 80px">
                <?php while (have_posts()):the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnails">
                            <div class="date">
                                <div class="day">
                                    <?php the_time('d'); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="month">
                                    <?php the_time('F'); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <img src=<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?> alt="" width="400" height="300">
                            <div class="thumb-text">
                                <div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                                <a href=<?php the_permalink(); ?> target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile ?>
            </div>
            <div><?php wp_numeric_posts_nav(); ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

I even tried to put the funtion call into the loop but still not working
Any help or clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this function to your functions.php

```
function theme_pagination($pages = '', $range = 3)
{

      global $wp_query;
      if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
      elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
      else { $paged = 1; }

      $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

      if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

      if($pages == '' && $pages != 0)
      {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
         if(!$pages)
         {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }   

     if(1 != $pages)
     {
         echo "<div class='pagination'>";
         if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
         if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a>";

         for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
         {
             if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
             {
                 echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
             }
         }

         if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>&rsaquo;</a>";  
         if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";
         echo "</div>\n";
     }

}
```

add this to the top of the index.php `global $wp_query;`

and use `theme_pagination($wp_query->max_num_pages);` instead of `wp_numeric_posts_nav();`

Answer (score 0):

To show pagination in blog page you have to use this function:

```
<?php the_posts_pagination( array(
      'mid_size' => 2,
      'prev_text' => 'Previous',
      'next_text' => 'Next'
    ) ); 
?>
```